# как завершить демонизированный сокет сервер

Tags: linux, c, сокет, demon

Есть сервер, я его доминизирую и включаю систему логов. Далее создается сокет, биндится к адресу, переводится в режим `listen` и в цикле принимает соединение, создается новый сокет в теле цикла, через новый сокет принимаются данные и идет ответ на них. Вот "псевдокод" (без обработки ошибок, считаем, что их нет):

```
volatile sig_atomic_t loop = 1;
void h1 (int s)
{
    signal(SIGUSR1, h1);
    loop = 0;
}
int main()
{
    close(0..2);
    open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY потом O_WRONLY потом O_WRONLY); // для 0 1 2 дескрипторов
    if (fork() > 0)
        exit(0);
    setsid();
    if (fork() > 0)
        exit(0); // завершаем основной процесс, создаем сессию, завершаем процесс, который лидер сессии.
    openlog...;
    signal(SIGUSR1, h1);
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in s_addr;
    s_addr...; // указываю семейство, порт, ип
    bind(s...);
    listen(s...);
    while (loop)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in for_accept;
        s_accept = accept(s...); // тут происходит ожидание
        if (!loop) { if(s_accept > 0) { shutdown(s_accept, ...); close(s_accept); } break; }
        recvfrom(s_accept, ..., (struct sockaddr*)&for_accept, ...); // и тут
        if (!loop) { if(s_accept > 0) { shutdown(s_accept, ...); close(s_accept); } break; }
        *какие-то манипулэйшн с данными*
        sendto(...);
        shutdown(s_accept, ...);
        close(s_accept);
    }
    shutdown(s, ...);
    close(s);
    exit(0);
}
```

Как грамотно завершать подобные процессы демоны? Я пытаюсь через консоль отправить SIGUSR1, но он так и висит в списке процессов и никак не меняется состояние. Два условия в цикле (!loop) для того, что бы после вызова ожидания запроса на соединение он не выполнял вообще дальше ничего, так же и про остальные вызовы.

P.S.: не важно что: sendto, recvfrom, send, recv, read или write я использую для SOCK_STREAM, мне так надо (recvfrom и sendto).

UPD: через gdb отладчик видно, что из accept он не выходит при получении сигнала. Я так понимаю нужно сделать accept не блокирующим и в цикле вызывать accept с паузой, допустим, 3 секунды, там же обрабатывать ошибки и прочее. Есть ли другой путь? В идеале я думал можно сделать так, что бы сервер всегда был в ожидании и при получении сигнала он просто выходил из этого вызова и завершал выполнение.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144639/discussion-on-question-by-nx4n-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

accept блокируется это правда. Вызывать его с паузой не надо.

Для обработки таких ситуаций [есть функция ppoll()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html#ppoll). Она блокируется и ждет когда будет событие на файле или появится сигнал.

После того как оно разблокируется проверяй флаги в обертке дескриптора. Дальше можно делать обычный accept() который моментально примет коннект.

Если флага нет, то значит отработал сигнал или таймаут.

Comment: Спасибо! Полезная функция. Создал структуру pollfd, добавил туда основной дескриптор сокета, в events поставил |= POLLIN, время и сигмаск сделал NULL. На условие (!fds.revents) сделал выход из цикла. Теперь по приходу сигнала программа завершается корректно. Иначе сразу срабатывает accept и дальше всё работает, сервер отвечает :)

Comment: Прикол в том, что в книге такое не описывается, а задание есть. Ну автор такой, он в принципе может проблему создать, не подсказывая, чтоб человек сам искал )